# Dead Outlet--GFCI RESET button stuck

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I have a dead kitchen outlet. Switching the circuit breaker won't bring it back. I looked at the GFCI and it looks like the RESET button might be stuck. This seems like my issue. Is there any way to repair this myself?

Thanks

Comment: Can you turn the breaker off, undo the outlet box cover, remove the mounting screws from the outlet, pull the outlet out (but do NOT undo the wires!) and post photos of the inside of the box? This *should* be a reasonably simple job, but I want to make sure before posting an answer....

Comment: Also, what happens if you try to push the RESET button back in?

Answer (score 4):

A GFCI is a safety alarm, which detects problems **in other devices**.  Its one job is to trip when another appliance has a problem.  It is testing all the appliances all the time.  If an appliance has a problem, it will not reset. That is its job.

I imagine with this GFCI tripped, a bunch of sockets are dead.  **Unplug everything in those sockets**.

Now go back and see if it will reset.

If it does, then the GFCI did exactly what it's supposed to.  Now start plugging things back in.  One of them will trip it.  That appliance is dead. Unplug it and take it to the repair shop.   Did that fix it?  Done.

OK next. Everything's unplugged?   OK.

After you do what ThreePhaseEel suggests, remove the two wires from the LOAD terminals.

Now power the circuit back up and see if the GFCI will behave normally.  If it does, the problem is in the downline wiring.  Or an appliance you haven't found yet!

If it still won't reset, then yeah, it's the GFCI.

Answer (score 2):

Considering the low cost of a new one, your obvious inexperience (or why would you be asking), almost certainly a lack of available spare parts, and the possibility of physical or property damage if you make a mistake, I recommend replacing the GCFI.